# Find content inside <td> using regex

Tags: php, html, regex

How can I extract "Areal" and "93 m²" by using Regex in scraping a html page?

```
<tr><td>Areal</td><td>93 m²</td></tr>
```

Please mind, that there are multiple `<tr> with <td>`'s inside this document, however there should only be one matching "Areal", "Rooms" etc.

Comment: Regex isn't great for parsing html. An html parser, like html5lib, is the standard approach. Check it out here: https://github.com/html5lib. It even notes that it is ideal for web-scrapers.

Comment: Frederik, would you consider accepting the below answer? Seems to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted what language you are using, so I'll just give the regex that matches you target text without any code of how to use the regex:

```
(?<=<td>).*?(?=</td>)
```

This uses a look-behind (a zero-width assertion) for `<td>`, a look-ahead for `</td>` and a non-greedy match (one that won't goggle up all input to the last `</td>`) for input between these two assertions.

---

In PHP:

```
$html = "<tr><td>Areal</td><td>93 m²</td></tr>";
preg_match_all("/(?<=<td>).*?(?=<\/td>)/", $html, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Areal
            [1] => 93 m²
        )

)
```

Comment: Im using PHP to try to grap the info.